# Using $_GET with for loop in PHP

Tags: php, get

I am trying to create a script that will get all keys from the url (url/?green&red&blue). I know I can use the $_GET array for that, but I don't fully understand how to use it.

What I want is a for loop that gets all values in order and then does something with it, for example print it.

I'm stuck here right now so if anyone can help me further it will be much appreciated!

Comment: There are already other questions related to the same topic, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171753/how-to-loop-through-a-set-of-get-values-in-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    echo "$key: $value<br />";
}
```

remember that you should sanitize your user input, so do not use the code in a production environment.

Comment: Crap, this was way better than my suggestion ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! Now I understand it too :D

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value){
  echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out.
if your url is (url/?green&red&blue)

You will get an array like this.

```
   Array
   (
        [green] => 
        [red] => 
        [blue] => 
    )
```

Your url will need to look like this ( url/?colora=green&colorb=red&colorc=blue )
So you get:

```
   Array
   (
       [colora] => green
       [colorb] => red
       [colorc] => blue
   )
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get them in javascript,
here is the code snippet.

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

The function returns an array/object with your URL parameters and their values.

Comment: The question is tagged as PHP and `$_GET` is clearly a PHP construct.